# Can't use HUION tablet on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: drivers, tablet

I've just installed the digimend drivers in order to use my tablet Huion 1060 plus new. I can make and install the source because no errors show up (except some SSL errors). After installing the drivers I reboot the system but my tablet is just recognized as a usb drive. 
Here's my `xinput --list` result:

```
 ⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0501:00 04F3:3019 Touchpad            id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ASUS   ASUS Wireless Mouse                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ HID 256c:006e Pad                         id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Beats Electronics Beats Solo Wireless     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ASUS   ASUS Wireless Mouse                id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ASUS   ASUS Wireless Mouse                id=18   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HID 256c:006e Pen                         id=20   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: same problem for h950p, have you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It worked out of the box for  me. BUT then I screwed around getting dual screens to work (to force the tablet to draw on one screen only in Krita or photoshop) and broke it.
Then I found this post, it worked for me, the main one didnt.

https://www.facebook.com/huion/posts/2042579912628124
Paweł Ziewiecki‎ to Huion
2 January · 
How to install Huion 1060 Plus on Ubuntu 17.04

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/kolrabi/digimend-kernel-drivers.git
cd digimend-kernel-drivers
make
sudo rmmod hid-kye
sudo rmmod hid-uclogic
sudo rmmod hid-huion
sudo make uninstall
sudo make install
```

reconnect the tablet or reboot the machine